# How to print folder name in h5 files

Tags: python, file, hdf5, directory-structure, h5py

I'm trying to access the file name of different folders in a h5 (hdf5) file. That is, if the file looks like this, I want to for instance print the whole path name for Axial force_window_locmax. There probably is a simple way to do this, but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to use Python to print this file structure.

[This is the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SrMF.png)

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: I'm trying to do it in Python!

Comment: See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: By "folder", do you mean the internal HDF5 Group/Dataset name path?

Comment: Yes, I mean the path to a data point in a HDF5 file.

Answer (score 1):

The internal Group/Dataset pathname is an attribute of each HDF5/h5py object. Objects include the file, groups and datasets (and others). The attribute is `.name` (clever, eh?). Example code below creates a file to mimic the schema of `timeseries.h5` with an empty dataset named `Axial force_window_locmax`. At the end it shows 3 different ways to reference the dataset object and print the full path name:

1. `ds` is the object from the dataset creation
2. `ds_obj` is an object created by referencing the dataset pathname
3. Using the file object (`h5f`) with the dataset pathname

See code below:

```
with h5py.File('SO_68095751.h5','w') as h5f:
    g = h5f.create_group('moor_lines/WF_AsIsHinCast/Dynamic/'+ \
                         'MooringLine1/segment_1/element_1/' )
    ds = g.create_dataset('Axial force_window_locmax',shape=(10,2))

    print(ds.name)

    ds_obj = h5f['/moor_lines/WF_AsIsHinCast/Dynamic/MooringLine1/'+ \
                  'segment_1/element_1/Axial force_window_locmax']
    print(ds_obj.name)        
 
    print(h5f['/moor_lines/WF_AsIsHinCast/Dynamic/MooringLine1/'+ \
              'segment_1/element_1/Axial force_window_locmax'].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) in Python, to print the path name of an object named `force_window_locmax` stored in any group/subgroup in an HDF5 file named `timeseries.h5` could be done as follows:

```
import HDFql

HDFql.execute("SHOW timeseries.h5 / LIKE **/^force_window_locmax$")

while HDFql.cursor_next() == HDFql.SUCCESS:
   print(HDFql.cursor_get_char())
```

This code snippet actually prints the path name of every object named `force_window_locmax` stored/found in different groups/subgroups. If you just have one object named as such in the HDF5 file then remove the loop and just print the name of the path.